# Install cURL in CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, curl

Can someone direct me on how to install cURL on a CentOS server. Preferably through WHM if it's possible to recompile PHP that way.. I am a noob in SSH and this is a production server.

Comment: I read somewhere you can do this in Easy Apache.. anyone know if this is true?

Comment: What is WHM?  And from the sounds of your post, you don't want curl per se, but the php wrapper around curl?

Comment: WHM CPanel.. and yes the PHP module, hence the tags: apache php curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egads, easyapache? SSH in, switch to root and "yum install curl".

Answer (score 0):

Got it installed... I did it through SSH though.. after switching to root (`su`) I ran `/scripts/easyapache`